# nestjs/cqrs - TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined on install

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

Trying to use the `@nestjs/crqrs` package, but i get the following error when launching npm install :

```
(node:77) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
api_1_305186ebcc50 |     at modules.map.module (/var/www/node_modules/@nestjs/cqrs/dist/services/explorer.service.js:29:49)
(node:77) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

I don't understand why, any idea ?

Here are my dependencies :

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^5.4.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^5.4.0",
    "@nestjs/cqrs": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^2.5.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.5",
    "class-validator": "^0.9.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "helmet": "^3.16.0",
    "pg": "^7.8.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "shortid": "^2.2.14",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.14",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^10.7.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.5",
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "supertest": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^23.1.3",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.5.0",
    "tslint": "5.11.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using different major versions for your nest dependencies (5 and 6). Since there were breaking changes they are not guaranteed to interoperate.

Update your `@nestjs` dependencies to v6 according to the [migration guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide) or alternatively, downgrade the `@nestjs/cqrs` package.